# Error: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ","

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

i'm getting a error on this line of code saying...

*Error: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ","*

It's no doubt something silly that i'm forgetting. 
Thanks!

```
    public func sendGetRequest(handler: public func getConnect (
    handler: dataFromURLCompletionClosure){
```

Comment: I have found this normally means I have missed a closing bracket somewhere - not necessarily in the line highlighted!

Comment: "public func" is not how you declare a function type. It's not clear what you want the `getConnect` parameter to be. I would recommend that you read some more about functions and parameters in the Swift book.

Comment: Are you trying to declare a function that takes a closure? What is the signature of the closure function you want to use?